# Smart way to Query data from database based on Language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, database-design

I'm always developing web applications that support both Arabic and English. Currently I'm doing something like this: *[Simplified]*

```
    @if (MyProject.Resources.Shared.SiteDirection == "ltr")
    {
        foreach (var Product in Model)
        {
            <b>@MyProject.Resources.Product.Index.ProductName</b> : <span>@Product.ProductName</span>
            <img src="@Product.ImagePath" />
        }
    }
    else if (MyProject.Resources.Shared.SiteDirection == "rtl")
    {
        foreach (var Product in Model)
        {
            <b>@MyProject.Resources.Product.Index.ProductName</b> : <span>@Product.ArabicProductName</span>
            <img src="@Product.ImagePath" />
        }
    }
```

Obviously I have the `Product` table which consist of `id`, `ProductName`, `ArabicProductName`, `ImagePath`. I'm using `@MyProject.Resources.Shared.SiteDirection` to set `dir` attribute for elements based on the language the user chose.

I'm asking for a smarter way to design the database, query the data -*keeping performance into account*- than what I'm doing right now, because it really gets *spaghetti-ous* in real projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not strictly about your DB question, but for example your view can look like this:

```
foreach (var Product in Model)
    {
        <b>@MyProject.Resources.Product.Index.ProductName</b> : <span>@(MyProject.Resources.Shared.SiteDirection == "ltr" ? Product.ProductName : Product.ArabicProductName)</span>
        <img src="@Product.ImagePath" />
    }
```

It's much more shorter and still readable I believe. And also advice don't use magic strings numbers etc like "ltr" - of course I know what it means, but use constants, when it need to be changed you'll have to just change the constant value not all occurences.

But still I believe much better approach would be to have only ProductName in ViewModel and when you map your business model or entity (depend on how much layers you have) you have to choose if ViewModel.ProductName = BusinessModel.ProductName or BusinessModel.ArabicProductName

**UPDATE**

So according to your comment you view should look like this:

```
foreach (var Product in Model)
    {
        <b>@MyProject.Resources.Product.Index.ProductName</b> : <span>@Product.Name</span>
        <img src="@Product.ImagePath" />
    }
```

Where `Product.Name` is depend on mapping your current `ProductName` or `ArabicProductName`, so in general this logic which you use (if/else) should be moved to the lower layer of application and the view should be just binded to the simples viewModel which need (of course in perfect world).

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but won't it be a performance hit to make the check for each iteration?

Comment: @Ahmed Of course it depend on collection amount, but in general I suggest to implement my second paragraph. ViewModel should has only neccessary properties and I believe you need to have only English or Arabic at the same time - not both.

Comment: Would you write a _simplified_ code for what you mean assuming that `Product` _Only_ has the above properties. I only need to show either the Arabic or the English `ProductName` and the `Image`.